# Switching tabs in chat occasionally turns part of the window black and removes content

Tags: support, bug, chat

Why am I getting screen like this after have switched tabs a couple of times?

[image]

This is normally what it looks like:

[image]

Edit: added 'bug' tag because the same problem can be reproduced by multiple people across different types of internet browsers.

Comment: Looks good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @frederic I assume the completely black areas are. This usually resolves in a couple of seconds for me.

Comment: @Jan, oh, that? Looks a lot like a browser issue to me, not sure we can do anything on our end.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @Light, well, the black artifacts are apparently covering the scrollbar gutter and arrows... Do you think styles could be responsible?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: There is a difference between "could not be responsible" and "we can not anything on our end". Devs have worked around crappy browser bugs for decades.

Comment: +1 Just reprod it in Chrome. This doesn't seem to be a Firefox only issue then.

Answer (score 1):

That's just Firefox bugging out. My Firefox suffers from the same issues, usually after prolonged use, and it can happen on any tab. You can see that parts of the chrome are being affected as well, so it's probably not a website issue.

A restart should fix it — it does for me. Well, until the next time it happens anyway.

Comment: Yes, it looks like an Aero problem. Does Firefox still leak memory like a sieve? It did the last time I tried it, about 128 versions ago. If so, that could explain what's going on here.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Pretty much.

Comment: @CodyGray It has improved a lot but there are still issues. Closing all my tabs except one and using *Minimize memory usage* in *about:memory* and then see FF still use more than 1GB of memory isn't what I'd expect.

Comment: You had very wonderful avatar. Why did you change it?